# Проблема с выборкой из массива

Tags: массивы, php

Сначала я помещаю все значения из бд в массив с помощью цикла, а как потом выводить таким образом **$lang['err_reg_off'];**

> Вот цикл

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM notice");
$lang = array();

while($row =$sql->fetch_array()){
   $lang[] = $row;
}
```

вот кусок массива:

```
array(11) { 
    [0]=> array(10) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        [1]=> string(125) "Ошибка! Логин должен содержать, только английские буквы!!" 
        ["text"]=> string(125) "Ошибка! Логин должен содержать, только английские буквы!!" 
        [2]=> string(4) "user" 
        ["module"]=> string(4) "user" 
        [3]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["lang"]=> string(1) "1" 
        [4]=> string(16) "err_userlogin_en" 
        ["title"]=> string(16) "err_userlogin_en" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(10) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "2" 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
        [1]=> string(26) "Сайт отключен!" 
        ["text"]=> string(26) "Сайт отключен!" 
        [2]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["module"]=> string(1) "0" 
        [3]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["lang"]=> string(1) "1" 
        [4]=> string(8) "site_off" 
        ["title"]=> string(8) "site_off" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(10) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "3" 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "3" 
        [1]=> string(77) "Ошибка! Регистрация отключена!
    }
}
```

где, 'err_reg_off' это название ошибки, а нужно выводить title, как мне поступить? сделать функцию для этого?

Comment: ваще не понятно что надо?

Answer (score 1):

А где у вас в куске массиве **`err_reg_off`**?

$lang содержит массив элементов, т.е. **$lang['`err_reg_off`'];** - не получится, надо как минимум **$lang[0]['`err_reg_off`'];** (ну либо **$lang[0]['title']** для `title`)

И почему **`fetch_array`**, особенно со значением по умолчанию **`MYSQL_BOTH`**? **`fetch_assoc`** чем-то хуже? Я так понял, что вам он нужен (ну либо тот же **`fetch_array`** но со вторым параметром **`MYSQL_ASSOC`**).

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понял, что Вам нужно, но вроде Вы имеете ввиду ассоциативный массив. Если это так то используйте функцию [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)